# Pandas transform DataFrame by adding rows from column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with `checking_date` and `checkout_date` of a reservation:

```
  checking_date checkout_date id
0    2020-11-08    2020-11-10 01
1    2019-09-06    2019-09-09 02
```

And I need to generate a new DataFrame that generates a series of days between `checking_date` and `checkout_date` and get me this:

```
             date id
0      2020-11-08 01
1      2020-10-09 01
2      2019-09-06 02
3      2019-09-07 02
4      2019-09-08 02
```

Any help is encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the number of days between out and in to be able to [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the row per id as needed. then increment the column date using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
# need datetime column
df['checking_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checking_date'])
df['checkout_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkout_date'])

# number of days between in and out
r = (df['checkout_date'] - df['checking_date']).dt.days
print(r)
# 0    2
# 1    3
# dtype: int64

# repeat the rows from df with the number or days
# rename the columns as wanted and reset the index
res = (
    df.loc[df.index.repeat(r), ['checking_date', 'id']]
      .rename(columns={'checking_date':'date'})
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)

# incrment days
res['date'] += pd.to_timedelta(res.groupby('id').cumcount(), unit='d')

print(res)
#         date  id
# 0 2020-11-08  01
# 1 2020-11-09  01
# 2 2019-09-06  02
# 3 2019-09-07  02
# 4 2019-09-08  02
```

If you don't have many rows in your original dataframe, using `apply` with [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) may be faster

```
res = (
    df[['id']]
      .assign(date = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['checking_date'], x['checkout_date'], 
                                                      closed='left'), axis=1))
      .explode('date')
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(res)
```

same result except columns order.